# In the following figure: $AE = ED$ , $BD = DC$. Prove that $BE = \frac{EF}{3}$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, triangles

The question is : $AE = ED$ , $BD = DC$. Prove that $BE = \cfrac{EF}{3}$

[image]

Approach:

[image]

Realisations:

$AD$ is a median of triangle $ABC$.

$BE$ is a median of triangle $DBA$.

$E$ is a centroid.

I tried to prove these triangles similar, but I was unsuccessful as one criteria is always missing.

Please help me with this problem.

---

How to do this using Ceva's Theorem?

Comment: How did you conclude that $BE$ is a median?

Comment: It is given that $AE = ED$. Also, I meant that $BE$ is a median of triangle $DBA$. Made an edit too.

Comment: something is not right. I do not see how it is possible that $3BE=EF$

Comment: @DestinyFindsYou Is it a generic triangle? Or equilater?

Comment: The problem is correct, but $E$ is not the centroid. The two medians are of two different triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote areas as [.] and establish the ratio
$$1=\frac{AE}{ED}= \frac{[ABF]}{[DBF]} = \frac{\frac{AF}{AC}[ABC]}{\frac12 (1-\frac{AF}{AC})[ABC]}\implies \frac{AF}{AC}=\frac13
$$
Then
$$
\frac{BE}{EF}= \frac{[ABD]}{[AFD]} 
=  \frac{\frac12[ABC]}{\frac12 \frac{AF}{AC}[ABC]}=\frac{AC}{AF}=3
$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply Menelaus' Theorem following B-C-A-D to see:

$$\frac{BD}{BC} \cdot \frac{FC}{AF}\cdot \frac{AE}{ED} =1 \implies \frac{AF}{FC}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Apply Menelaus' Theorem again, this time following A-C-B-F to see:

$$\frac{AF}{AC} \cdot \frac{DC}{BD}\cdot \frac{BE}{EF}=1 \implies \frac{BE}{EF}=3$$